# Quiero crear un slider para cada una de las barras de mi diagrama

Tags: slider

## Este es el código de mi diagrama de barras:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [12,8]

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

#Datos

x = ["Elección1", "Elección2", "Elección3", "Elección4", "Elección5", "Elección6", 
"Elección7", "Elección8"]

y = [0.3, 1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2, 1, 0.5, 1]

colores = ["#7f7f7f", "#FFFF00", "#8A2BE2", "#DC143C", "#7FFFD4", "#1f77b4", "#008080", 
"#F4A460"]

#Gráfico de barras

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x = x, height = y, color = colores)

plt.show()
```

#y quiero agregar un slider a cada Elección, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que con el slider, cada barra de mi diagrama pueda subir o bajar.
De antemano gracias por la colacboración!

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y añade en las etiquetas con qué lenguaje estás trabajando.